# Download files from Domino Server through Worklight's Adapters

Tags: cookies, cross-domain, download, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm currently developping an application on Worklight (HTML, JS and CSS) and i have to fetch data and files from a secure Lotus Domino Server.

- I'm using an **HTTP Adapter** to log in the server and query it and it works fine. But now i'm trying to download files from the Domino Server through the adapter. I created an JAVA agent on the **server which base64 encode the file's data**. So i fetch the encoded data using the adapter and send it back to the application. Then the **application decodes it and write the file** using the Cordova File API. But some **characters got altered** during this process and the **resulting file is different from the original one**. Does anyone try this before and encounter this issue ? Or is there **another way to download a file in a Worklight app**, while avoiding the **"cross-domain policy" issue** ?
- I'm considering **configure the server to accept cross-domain requests from the app to the server directly**. But in that case, the **cookie from the authentification form would be store in the application** itself. Does anyone knows if, once the application is deployed, **the application is able to store and use cookies** ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally **deployed my application on iOS devices**. And it seems that the **application's webviewer is able to store cookies and launch cross-domain requests**.So if you're in the same situation as me, you can consider developping your application using a **direct dialog between your application and your server** via cross-domain requests. With this, you can also **download files without using an adapter** and easily by using the Cordova API.